# Is a dedicated DHCP server required for PXE boot?

Tags: cisco, switch, dhcp

Read a lot of posts on PXE server setup. Most of them mention to setup DHCP server. My question is even though we used a managed switch (e.g. Cisco SG-300), which comes with DHCP functionality, do we still need a dedicated DHCP server?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network. Your switch will not have the boot images for your hosts.

Comment: Hello WM and welcome. You definitely don't want *another* DHCP server, and the short answer is simply any DHCP server software will work, so long as you are able to configure the required DHCP options (eg `server-name`, `filename`, possibly others) and you have a working TFTP server (or whatever your PXE clients will boot from.)  Certainly Cisco IOS DHCP works, manual indicates SG-300 DHCP also would work.

Comment: I've only seen PXE boot work when the DHCP was on the same segment. Helper-addresses through a gateway never seemed to work for me.

Comment: @aletoledo I believe the original question was about DHCP on the switch, not with DHCP-relay on the switch; though I don't see why the relay would make a difference as the client doesn't know the difference.  Though I've seen TFTP clients which wouldn't go through a router.  Certainly I agree with you that many PXE clients are fussy and/or fragile.